# Adding an If statement inside an Update in MySQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mamp

I am very new to MySQL and I have a project due on Monday. 
I have an issue trying to add a query/trigger to do the following:

My project breif states "when a customer registers, they recieve 30 days free trial for customer service, after that they pay"
So I am trying (and failing) to add something that will check if the account has been registered for 30 days, if it has, the account type will change to "Paid Subscription", if not it will stay as "Free Trail"

I  can get this to work seperately, but not together.

Here is my table:

```
 customer_id varchar (100) NOT NULL,
  first_name varchar (20) not null,
  last_name varchar (20) not null,
  phone_no varchar (20) not null,
  email_address varchar (20) not null,
  address varchar (100) not null,
  city varchar (20) not null,
  country varchar (20) not null,
  date_of_registration date,
  account_type varchar (20) not null,
  PRIMARY KEY (customer_id)
  ) DATA DIRECTORY='c:/mamp';
```

thank you!

Comment: Try and use `VARCHAR(255)` as a default and only restrict that if you have a very compelling reason. For many things, like names and email addresses, shorter fields can cause huge hassles for your users.

Comment: Hint: There's no conventional `IF` in MySQL when making queries. Instead use `WHERE`.

Comment: @tadman IF is totally accepted in Mysql see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/if.html

Comment: @Sylwit That's within stored procedures only, not regular queries.

Comment: @tadman Works the same check this example https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8rJ5jw37Fu9Fq5NPXAQNYe/1

Comment: @Sylwit That's the [`IF()` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if), not an `IF` statement. That's why I said it's not "conventional". In most languages (e.g. PHP) `if` is a flow-control statement.

Answer (score 1):

According to what you ask, you can do something like this (for the syntax of IF)

```
SELECT 
    first_name, last_name, email_address,
    IF(NOW() > date_of_registration + INTERVAL 30 DAY, 'paid', 'free') as status
FROM users WHERE id = XX
```

Of course select fields you want and adapt the WHERE clause to your need.
You will have a status value which will contain "paid" or "free"

!!! BUT !!! this is probably not what you want from a logical point of view. In fact the previous query return "paid" if the account is older than 30 days. You have to check the account_type in your processing after.

I would suggest you to add a available_until field:

- user register => account_type = "free", available_until = NOW() + 30d

If user pays within 30 days.
After the payment, SET account_type = "paid" and available_until = {time you want}

You now have only check if the account available_until is after the current day and you don't really care about the type of account.